# How to create selectable item view in native iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to create a selectable view in ios like the following image. How to create like this??
Have any idea or suggestion...When I select any one from these that was selected.

[image: Example image]

Comment: So you want to create a drop down menu view ? That can be created using a UITableView. You put the tableView as a subclass and in your dropDownView class .h, create a protocol that handles the myTableViewDidSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex. This is just for guidance, not working code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `UIButton` and `UITableView` or by using `UITextField` ,`UIGestureRecogniser` and `UITableView` ,or once have a look at this [DropDownList](http://code4app.net/ios/NIDropDown/50fe226e6803fa9c52000000)